# Copy Range, Paste into New Workbook, Multiple Files, Delete Blank Rows

Tags: excel, vba, automation

First time poster here. I've been reading tutorials/guides all day and made a lot of strides, but am having a tough time figuring out how to write a macro that does what I want to do.

I get around 100 time sheets per week that are then copied and imported into an accounting software. The sheets are all based off of a template, are in separate workbooks, and have a worksheet titled "Pre Import Time Card" within them. I copy the values from each book's pre import worksheet into a new file and upload them to our accounting software as a batch.

I want to have a macro open each file automatically, copy the range A1:I151 on each workbook, and then paste the values into a new worksheet. Because of the import templates design, this inevitably leads to many blank rows within the specified range. I would like to delete any blank rows as a final step.

UPDATE: I HAVE COPIED THE CODE TO REFLECT WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE.Also a list of new problems is below.

- pasting to next unused row is not working
- I need to figure out how to kill the old file / not have it enter the same file twice.
- I would like to suppress the "Privacy warning on VBA / Active X controls" dialog that comes up at each save.
- It's not currently copying correctly. I'm getting a bug at the rDest.Resize line.
- Object variable or With Block Variable not set.

I had it running when using file names in an array, but decided that was unnecessary and to use a For.. Each loop.

```
Sub CopySourceValuesToDestination()

    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim sDestPath As String
    Dim sSourcePath As String
    Dim aFile As String
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TSSize As Object
    Dim objFso As Object 'New FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Object 'Folder
    Dim objFile As Object 'File
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    sDestPath = "Z:\Dropbox\My Documents\TimeSheets\Processed\"
    sSourcePath = "Z:\Dropbox\My Documents\TimeSheets\Copying\"

    'Open the destination workbook at put the destination sheet in a variable
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(sDestPath & "Destination.xlsm")
    Set shDest = wbDest.Sheets(1)

    Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(sSourcePath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    aFile = objFile.Name
    Set objWb = Workbooks.Open(sSourcePath & aFile)

        'find the next cell in col A
        Set rDest = shDest.Cells(xlLastRow + 1, 1)
        'write the values from source into destination
        TSSize = wbSource.Sheets(4).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        rDest.Resize(TSSize, 9).Value = wbSource.Sheets(4).Range("A1:I" & TSSize).Value

        wbSource.Close False
        wbDest.SaveAs sDestPath & "Destination.xlsm"
        wbDest.Close
        Kill sSourcePath & wbSource
        Next
End Sub
Function xlLastRow(Optional WorksheetName As String) As Long

     '    find the last populated row in a worksheet

    If WorksheetName = vbNullString Then
        WorksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    End If
    With Worksheets(1)
        xlLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1), xlFormulas, _
        xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: had you considered just sorting the results so the blanks end up grouped at the bottom and delete them? Or autofilter out blanks before the copy paste?

Comment: The data range is not continuous.. The blanks are located unpredictably.

Comment: I can sort the blanks after or before if it can be used in a macro, but when manually sorting sometimes the records would be located at the top and one stray would end up at the bottom. The blank cells actually all have 0's located in the E column, because the formula used created a 0 row for 0 man hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provded your datarange in the time sheet is continuous you can replace

```
rDest.Resize(151,9).Value = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("A1:I151").Value
```

with

```
var for storing 
dim TSsize as long

TSsize = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("A1").end(xlDown).Row
rDest.Resize(TSsize,9).Value = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("A1:I" & TSsize).Value
```

This is prevent the empty rows from getting into your sheet in the first place.

If the each time sheet is not a continuous range you can interate through the rows looking for empty rows and deleting them. Let me know if that is the case and i will update my answer.